# How to show a successful login popup message when the successful login can go to a redirect url?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, popup, http-post

I have the following login post action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Auditing]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel details, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(details.Name,
                details.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid name or password.");
            }
            else
            {
                ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                   DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                ident.AddClaims(LocationClaimsProvider.GetClaims(ident));
                ident.AddClaims(ClaimsRoles.CreateRolesFromClaims(ident));
                AuthManager.SignOut();
                AuthManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = false
                }, ident);


                //Persist login into DB upon successful login
                Loginrecord login = new Loginrecord();
                login.Username = user.UserName;
                login.SessionId = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
                Session["sessionid"] = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
                login.Date = DateTime.Now;
                SQLLoginrecord sqlLogin = new SQLLoginrecord();
                sqlLogin.PutOrPostLogin(login);
                //End addition

                return Redirect(returnUrl);


            }

        }
        ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(details);
    }
```

Since a successful login from this action can go to any authorization-requiring page the user types the URL for in the address bar of the browser, how can I show a popup message that indicates a successful login? If I were to go with the ViewBag approach and add a Success variable, do I have to access that ViewBag from every View (including some that do not have a shared Layout) of the application that requires authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` method is going to issue a 302 response to the browser with the new url in the location header and browser will make a totally new Http request for that url. So ViewBag is not going to help you.

You might consider using `TempData` (which works for the next call) to share data from your Login action method to any other action method. You can write an action filter which checks the TempData item and set the approriate ViewBag entry so that you can do whatever you want in your other views.

```
public class LoginMsg : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var msg=filterContext.Controller.TempData["LoginMsg"] as string;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.LoginMsg= msg;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now in your Login class, before redirecting, set the TempData

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel details, string returnUrl)
{ 
    // do stuff
    TempData["LoginMsg"]="Logged in successfully";
    return Redirect(returnUrl); 
}
```

Now decorate your other action methods (or you can do it on controller level) with our action filter.

```
[LoginMsg]
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
   return View();
}
```

In your view or the _Layout, you can access the ViewBag item and call the code to the trigger your popup control.

```
<script>
    var msg = "@ViewBag.Msg";
    if (msg.length) {
        // alert(msg);
        // Call the code to fire the popup now
        // yourMagicPopupPlugin.Popup(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked in my application. I had to change the LoginMsg decoration to LoginMsgFilter (wouldn't compile otherwise). Then I added a cshtml in the Shared folder of Views called popup_login.cshtml as follows: @{
    var message = TempData["LoginMsg"] ?? string.Empty;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if (message)
    alert(message);
</script> And in each of the views I wanted the popup to appear I added @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/popup_login.cshtml") . Is this the best approach?

Comment: You can put it in the layout. see the updated answer.